# SQL insert statement without defining data types

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, dynamic

I was asked by a local school to write a database export utility to export data from a popular school management program to one that the government requires. The reason being that the government only accepts quarterly reports from its own program.

After ALLOT of hours spent just figuring out the relationships in the poorly written government database I finally compiled my SQL statement requirements but I have a problem.

Due to the poor design and use of data types and columns in the program I am having trouble dynamically putting together the SQL insert statements. Is there a way to create a single SQL statement  with the data (formatted correctly)  without specifying the data type and insert it into the table?
To give you an Idea there are 192 tables with at least 20 columns each.

Update: This is how my program currently works.
Collect data->Compare required column data type in excel sheet->Format data->Generate SQL Statement->Execute statement

Comment: INSERT statement does not require data type IMHO, could you provide some example?

Comment: Ok simple one Student_Info table. First 7 column types are autonumber, text, text, text, date, number, yes/no and so on for 31 columns

Comment: Perhaps @the_joric meant an example of an *INSERT statement* where you seem to have the necessity of specifying data types. I second that INSERT doesn't require data types to be specified (as far as I can remember).

Comment: What language? If .NET you can use Paramerters and `AddWithValue`.

Comment: Is your issue right now that the datatypes are not the same in your school access database as the government one so an implict cast cannot occur?

Comment: INSERT INTO Student_Info (LearnerID, AccessionNo, TheDate, SName, FName, NickName, BirthDate, IDNo, Gender, HomeLanguage, InstructionLanguage, PreferredLanguage, Address1, Address2, Address3, AddressCode, Grade, Class, GradeYears) VALUES ('" + data [i][0] + "', '" + data [i][0] + "', '" + data [i][29] + "', '" + data [i][3] + "', '" + data [i][8] + "', '" + data [i][2] + "', '" + data [i][11] + "', '" + data [i][10] + "', '" + data [i][14] + "', " + data [i][12] + ", " + data [i][102] + ", " + data [i][108] + ", '" + data [i][82] + "', '" + data [i][83] + "', '" + data

Comment: The 2 databases are different in both data types and format so I have to do the conversion (Not the problem). I program in Java

Comment: if this a when to surround your parameters with single quotes you could use the system tables in access and a cross reference table of your data to automatically generate the quotes on specific datatypes.

Comment: I have done that. I use an excel sheet that I specify the data types in and my program formats the data but I just hoped there was a way I could pass everything as for instance String to the database and it would just insert it if the format is correct.

Comment: If this is java just use a prepared statement and generate the set methods dynamically.

Comment: The insert statement I pasted above was part of my prepared statement (cut to fit in space). The data in the data array that gets passed is already formatted as needed but I still need to compile a statement like this for all the 192 tables and this is kind of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can quote everything so it will be passed as string. Of course, the data types must mach:

```
create table testDataType(
myInt int,
myDateTime datetime,
myfloat numeric(5,2))


insert into testDataType values ('1','01/01/2012','5.3')
(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: I like this, but will it work for all data types. I'm talking about memo's, yes/no, autonumber and so on?

Comment: I quickly put together a test program based on your advice and looks like I made a mistake while previously testing it this way (left out some '). Got all the data types needed to work. Thanks

Comment: @Griffin: you might be better off using an unambiguous `DATETIME` literal (and always including a time element is a good aide memoire to the fact that `DATETIME` values always have a time element!) e.g. `'2012-02-14 00:00:00'`.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through using the datatypes from the metadata.  If it isn't an array of variants and it is string you will have to add in parseInt or something similar.

```
      String selectStatement = "insert into wide_table (b1,b2,b3....) values (?,?,?.....) ";
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(selectStatement);


        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT top 1 * FROM WIDE_TABLE");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        for(int i =0;i<numerOfColumns;i++)
        {
          String x = rsmd.getColumnType(numerOfColumns)         
          if(x.equals("varchar"))
          {
              prepStmt.setString(numerOfColumns, data[numerOfColumns]);
          }
          else if(x.equals("int"))
          {
              prepStmt.setInt(numerOfColumns, data[numerOfColumns]);

          }
....
        }

        ResultSet rs2 = prepStmt.executeQuery();
```